# Are tricycles, recumbents and velomobiles on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

Recumbents and velomobiles are banned from international bicycling championships, because they are too fast. Many are tricycles and therefore technically not bicycles. Is it on-topic to ask questions related to tricycles, recumbants and velomobiles on the **bi**cycles stack-exchange?

Comment: Related: [Can I ask questions about unicycles here?](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/659/can-i-ask-questions-about-unicycles-here)

Comment: See also the recent [flying bike question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/is-there-any-bicycle-that-can-fly), and the chat discussion http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/conversation/are-flying-bikes-on-topic.

Answer (score 12):

Generally yes - questions about wheeled vehicles operated by pedals are generally acceptable regardless of whether said vehicle has 1, 2 or more wheels and irrespective of how you sit on the vehicle.

That said, you will still need to make sure that your questions have a broad enough appeal and meet the other condition of the [FAQ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq).